# How to resolve some json with the angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to resolve some data directly in the router, like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'users/:userId',
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: {
            profile: { name: 'John Doe', .... }
        }
    }
];
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubmbku?file=app%2Fapp.router.ts)

So, when I navigate to this route I get the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for John Doe!
```

The question I have, is how can I resolve static `json`

Comment: check https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: That describes a solution to an other problem. I just want some static data in my route, just a described [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I think you missed the most important, declaring your RouterModule asRoot() in AppModule, and define a main provider / service to manage Route request : https://angular.io/guide/router#add-heroes-functionality

Comment: I did all that. Routing works like a charm, but as stated below, I should replace `resolve` with `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `resolve` to `data`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'users/:userId',
        component: UserComponent,
        data: {
            profile: { name: 'John Doe', .... }
        }
    }
];
```

Access that data via the route snapshot:

```
this.route.snapshot.data['profile'];
```

where `this.route` is the activated route service that is injected into the component you are working in.

```
export class UserComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
}
```